# normalising and std scaling dataset in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset that has 77 columns. I combined all values with VectorAssembler, and then to scale it I'm using MinMaxScaler. The scaler code:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(inputCol="normalised", outputCol="scaled")
train = scaler.fit(temp_train.select("normalised"))
train = train.transform(temp_train)
```

I set the stages for pipeline as

```
stages = []
stages += string_indexer
stages += one_hot_encoder
stages += [numVector]
stages += [scaler]
```

numVector is the VectorAssembler which makes a column named 'normalised' and scaler is the MinMaxScaler

but then when I try to execute the pipeline

```
%%time
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline().setStages(stages)
model = pipeline.fit(train)

pp_df = model.transform(test)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

E:\PySpark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    127                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    128             else:
--> 129                 return self._fit(dataset)
    130         else:
    131             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

E:\PySpark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\pipeline.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    105                 if isinstance(stage, Transformer):
    106                     transformers.append(stage)
--> 107                     dataset = stage.transform(dataset)
    108                 else:  # must be an Estimator
    109                     model = stage.fit(dataset)

E:\PySpark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\base.py in transform(self, dataset, params)
    168                 return self.copy(params)._transform(dataset)
    169             else:
--> 170                 return self._transform(dataset)
    171         else:
    172             raise ValueError("Params must be a param map but got %s." % type(params))

E:\PySpark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _transform(self, dataset)
    336     def _transform(self, dataset):
    337         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 338         return DataFrame(self._java_obj.transform(dataset._jdf), dataset.sql_ctx)
    339 
    340 

E:\PySpark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

E:\PySpark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    132                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    133                 # JVM exception message.
--> 134                 raise_from(converted)
    135             else:
    136                 raise

E:\PySpark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in raise_from(e)

IllegalArgumentException: Output column normalised already exists.
```

The last line:
Output column normalised already exists.

seems to be the problem. Can anyone tell me a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out that running the fit and transform instantly after declaring the scaler is altering the dataframe and that's why the error said, it already exists. I removed the fit and transforms of numVector and scaler. So, the fit and transforms only happens in the pipeline and the columns are scaled.